# Unable to delete a partition in Yosemite

Tags: macos, partition

When I was beta testing Yosemite I had installed the beta version in a partition on my disk. Now that I have upgraded my computer to Yosemite I would like to delete the beta testing partition.

However when I run Disk Utility I no longer see the two partitions as children of a single disk but each with their own parent disk (which I presume is because Yosemite converts hard disks to use Core Storage volumes?)

[image: Disk Utility showing Partition tab]

More importantly I can no longer add, remove or resize partitions at all - all options are greyed. I tried rebooting into the Recovery disk but had the same problem there. Solution?

Comment: 2 possibilities [I haven't tried either as I won't go near Yosemite until this Core Storage pain is alleviated] - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142934/trouble-with-my-partitions?rq=1 - or - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60583/cant-ever-remove-partition?rq=1